# Sum of Pareto r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

I know that $X_i (i=1,2,...,n)$ are i.i.d. Pareto r.v. with parameter = $3$ and mean = $2$. I need to calculate $P(X_1 + ... + X_{40} > 90)$ using a normal approximation.

I understand that any linear combinations of $X_i$ would be Pareto distributed as well. But what the normal approximation as to do with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an i.i.d. collection of random variables $X_1,X_2, \ldots$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $Z_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to a $N(0,1)$ random variable by the central limit theorem. This means that $P(Z_n \leq z) \to P(N(0,1) \leq z)$ as $n \to \infty$ for any real number $z$.

In this case, you can write the desired probability as $P(Z_{40} > c)$ for some value $c$ and then approximate it as $P(N(0,1) >c)$.

Comment: Thanks. I got it that you are using the Central Limit Theorem (using the hint of the normal approximation). But I don't quite understand the last part. How do I go numbers from it ?

Comment: Take $P(Z_{40} > c)$ and write it as $P(\sum_{i=1}^{40} X_i > blah)$ (this is just rearranging the inequality $(\sum_{i=1}^{40} (X_i - \mu))/(\sigma \sqrt{40})>c$ to be $\sum_{i=1}^{40} X_i > blah$ and then looking at the problem, picking $c$ so that $blah=90$) . $\mu,\sigma^2$ are the parameters of $X_i$.

Comment: I understand that rearrangements but how do I get the sigma if i don't know the value $X_m$ in the formula of the variance in Pareto distribution ?

Comment: You find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ by using the parameters of the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) (your definition may vary from Wiki). Plug the parameters you are given into the expressions for the mean and variance in terms of those parameters for the Pareto distribution.

Comment: Alright I've inferred the $x_m$  knowing the formula for the mean and it's value (here=2) so i finished with $1 - P(Z<=1.369) = 0.0869$